# Como gerar código na div em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Queria saber como colocar um código `html` em uma `tag div` usando `javascript

Também gostaria de uma explicação sobre como fazer para redirecionar alguém pra minha página caso alguém remova o meu id da pagina, já vi isso antes, designers criam temas e colocam para que os usuários não remova os créditos...

Comment: Já pensou em contratar o serviço de um desenvolvedor para fazer isso pra você?

Comment: "designers criam temas e colocam para que os usuários não remova os créditos" Geralmente isso aí é feito por molecada que codifica um script de redirecionamento com base64, escape de caracteres, ou coisa do tipo, só pra curioso não copiar. Na prática, não funciona pra nada, pois é extremamente simples de remover. Sugestão: não perca tempo com essas bobeiras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim com o jQuery: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grxLjG

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elemento = $('#Creditos');
  if (elemento.length > 0) {
    elemento.text('Seu texto vai aqui');
  } else {
    window.location = 'http://github.com';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Creditos"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementByClassName('Creditos').innerHtml('codigo html aqui');
```

Imagino que você queira caso alguem copie seu codigo fonte e remover o crédito ele identifique e redirecione para a sua página, isso partindo do pre suposto que a pessoa não vai remover o código que faça isso tb.

Seria algo assim:

```
if(!document.getElementByClassName("Creditos")){
    window.location = "http://www.suapagina.com.br";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, simples, pode fazer assim:

```
<div id="Creditos"></div>
```

ai no JS:

```
var Teste = {

init: function(){

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute("class", "classe_do_label");
    label.innerHTML = "Teste Label";

    document.getElementById('creditos').appendChild(label);
}};
window.onload = Teste.init();
```

Neste exemplo criei um label no JS adicionei uma classe nele e adicionei o texto teste label e inseri ele no html pelo JS mesmo.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços

;)